# How to find implementation file made by Interface Builder?

Tags: cocoa

I made an object in Interface Builder. Then I told it to write the class files. But when I go to XCode I can't find the implementation or header files. How can I edit the implementation file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class files are wherever you saved them. So, go there, move them somewhere else if you want, and then add them to your Xcode project.